# Force fullscreen from Firefox Developper tools

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

My situation is a bit stranger than usual. I'm writing Node.JS application that will control Firefox Browser via Remote Debugging Protocol. The aim is to automate playing Netflix videos for our home projector. I am currently able to execute console commands from the debugger.

I can get all the way to playing the selected entry in Netflix, but the problem is that it's not in fullscreen. Running `document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()` will give out an error, because it's only allowed from trusted event callback.

I also tried to create trusted click event to trigger the request, but that won't work either:

[image]

Is there a way to force fulscreen using Firefox Developper Tools? I do not need this to work from regular javascript that runs in the webpage, just the console.

Comment: The Remote Debugging Protocol should give you access to a console that is in the Browser context (or, at least, such a console is available with the Firefox Browser Toolbox, which appears to use the Remote Debugging Protocol). That console is in a higher privilege context than is available to either in-page JavaScript or WebExtension based extensions. That console is in the same context legacy XUL and bootstrap used to run in. You *definitely* should be able to enable fullscreen mode from there. However, I haven't done the research to determine what would be needed to do so.

Comment: Alternately, from that context you can create trusted events, which would permit a round-about way of doing this. However, that shouldn't be necessary, as that context should permit you to do a very large variety of actions.

Answer (score -1):

If i'm not wrong, there's no way to start FF in fullscreen mode except with some addon or user action.
If you can, use Chrome with --kiosk.